# Calling the Arrays in Json

Tags: javascript, json

we have json data like

```
Orgnaizationunit [ 
{"name":london , "Coordinates":[39.78,22.30]} , 
{"name" : Newyork, "Coordinates":[39.81,22.37}
]
```

In JavaScript we can call first element in array as

```
Organizationunit[0].name
```

I want to know how to call coordinates. I called it like

```
Organizationunit[0].Coordinates[0][1]
```

But i am getting Undefined Error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this

```js
var Orgnaizationunit = [ 
  {"name": 'london', "Coordinates":[39.78,22.30]}, 
  {"name": 'Newyork', "Coordinates":[39.81,22.37]}
];
   
console.log(Orgnaizationunit[0].Coordinates[0]);
console.log(Orgnaizationunit[0].Coordinates[1]);
```